# (Re)Sources on regaining spirituality and comprehension of Torah after sin

Tags: torah-study, mysticism-kabbalah, sin, chasidut-hasidism, tikkunim

The Ramak [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Or_Neerav%2C_PART_III.2.4?ven=Moses_Cordovero%27s_Introduction_to_Kabbalah,_Annotated_trans._of_Or_ne%27erav,_Ira_Robinson,_1994.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that when one sins, the sin will serve as a shell (kelipah) that will prevent one from comprehending the esoteric part of Torah.

> In the book of Tikkunim they stated explicitly that sin is a shell [which prevents] the intellect from comprehending the esoteric.

My question is: are there any (re)sources that discuss the idea that:

a) sinning will result in a person not being fully able to delve into Torah concepts and to fully understands what he learns. He hovers over the text, but the text will not be accesibble to him

and do these (re)sources discuss:

b) the remedy for regaining the abillity (spiritual) of comprehending the Torah a person learns and to understand it?

There are a plethora of tikkunim, but I could not find any that discuss the above. If a person feels that, due to his sins, isn't able to fully comprehend and study the Torah, what should that person do?

---

**Edit:** TheGrapke cites the Gemara in [Yoma 39a](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.39a.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), which says that the heart will become "venitamtem"  -stupefied when "venitmetem" - impurified. [Rashi (sv. מטמטמת)](https://www.sefaria.org/Yoma.39a.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) says that the impurity will "clog up the wisdom in one's heart". A similair idea is given by the Ramchal in [Mesilas Yesharim (chapter 11)](https://www.sefaria.org/Mesilat_Yesharim.11.56?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> For sin dulls a man's heart, causing to depart from him true knowledge and the spirit of wisdom which the Holy One, blessed be He, bestows to the pious

So, according to the sources mentioned above, sin(s) causes a diminish of wisdom in a person's heart. That's clear from the sources.

However, are there sources that explain what to do when such a loss in wisdom occures? Simply saying "study Torah" in this case isn't easy, because sometimes the "clogged up brain" will not comprehend the Torah a person learns. What to do when that happens?

Please provide sources in the answer and I would love to have it in English.

Comment: Hi, do you know for sure that there is a remedy? And do you have any reason to believe that it is not simply just doing proper teshuva? Either way, such a work sounds immensely valuable and I hope you find what you are looking for +1

Comment: Try looking at Psalms 51.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thank you! There are many tikkunim for different kinds of sins. But I haven't stumbled upon a "remedy" for feeling spiritually "down" and thus not being able to comprehend your studies. I have a feeling there must be works/words/sources that discuss this.

Comment: @N.T. ah, the "classic one" :). I think [Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.51.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says something familiair to this, e.g. that the heart is concealed. Is that concealed because of sin? Nevertheless, I am still wondering if there are any classical/contemporary/kabbalistic sources that give a remedy for someone who feels "disconnected" from learning, G-d forbid, in order to re-connect to Torah.

Comment: Maybe this question has a general/specific divide? Each aveira and mitzva neglected will damage a specific part of one's soul (Arizal et al), so when we learn anything relevant to it, the lesson will be lessened. The part of our soul that we should recognise when we learn it will not respond properly and we won't connect to it. It would take deep knowledge of one's _specific_ sins, as well as the subject, to know which specific tikunim to do, which is why the _general_ advice to this question is to just do as much teshuva, learn as much Torah, and do as many mitzvot and good deeds as possible

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what I've meant. You hit the nail! What if, due to ones sins, one isn't able to focus and comprehend on the Torah he learns. He just sits and learns a sugya, Tosfos, Rashi etc... but it doesn't enter him so to speak. What should one do in that case?

Comment: https://chabadlibrary.org/books/admur/tm/1/32/178.htm

Comment: https://daf-yomi.com/DYItemDetails.aspx?itemId=25154

Comment: @Shmosel wonderful. Does the article say that when impure, studying Torah will re-ignite the inner flame? I feel that this could be a potential answer if you would a) translate it, b) include the sources.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE I don't see how this answers the question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Shmuel The original source for the idea presented in the question is אל תקרי ונטמאתם אלא ונטמטם (יומא לט ע"א) . So the question is, so what do you do next? There is a famous story about Rb Akiva Eiger which is possibly not true that the answer is to go into galus. Regardless of whether or not the story is true the point seems to be that you have to break you connection with your former self.

Comment: Have you tried R' Tzadok miLublin's "Tzidkas HaTzadik?"

Comment: @Shalom Not on this subject....

Comment: There is a Zohar passage somewhere that cites wormwood as a cure for this, and there are those in our times who take very small shots of absinthe with the intention of fixing this.

Comment: @shmosel would you be willing to put that into an answer (English and including all sources mentioned)?

Comment: No, sorry. But if anyone wants to run with it, feel free.